# How do I remove a Git worktree that contains a submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-worktree

Let’s say that I have a Git repo that contains a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefsubmoduleasubmodule):

```
$ mkdir main-worktree
$ cd main-worktree
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /…/main-worktree/.git/
$ git submodule add https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git Hello-World
Cloning into '/…/main-worktree/Hello-World'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 13, done.
remote: Total 13 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 13
Receiving objects: 100% (13/13), done.
$ git commit -m 'Create submodule'
[main (root-commit) 66070b6] Create submodule
 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitmodules
 create mode 160000 Hello-World
```

and then create another [worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefworktreeaworktree) for that repo (one that contains the [submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefsubmoduleasubmodule)):

```
$ git worktree add ../secondary-worktree
Preparing worktree (new branch 'secondary-worktree')
HEAD is now at 66070b6 Create submodule
$ cd ../secondary-worktree
$ git submodule update
Cloning into '/…/secondary-worktree/Hello-World'...
Submodule path 'Hello-World': checked out '7fd1a60b01f91b314f59955a4e4d4e80d8edf11d'
```

How do I remove the `secondary-worktree` that I just created? I tried using `git worktree remove`, but it gave me an error:

```
$ cd <path-to-main-worktree>
$ git worktree remove ../secondary-worktree
fatal: working trees containing submodules cannot be moved or removed
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[You can use `--force` to remove a worktree that contains submodules:](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#Documentation/git-worktree.txt-remove)

```bash
git worktree remove --force <path-to-worktree-with-submodules>
```